# Recaptcha BROWSER_ERROR

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

Some days ago we have upgraded to Recaptcha Enterprise.
It seems that the only support channel is here on stackoverflow

What mean BROWSER_ERROR in invalidReason?

in the official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.assessments#InvalidReason)

it's not specified

```
{
"name": "projects/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"event": {
"token": "xxxxxxx",
"siteKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; Redmi Note 8T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.105 Mobile Safari/537.36",
"userIpAddress": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
"expectedAction": "login"
},
"score": 0,
"tokenProperties": {
"valid": false,
"invalidReason": "BROWSER_ERROR",
"hostname": "",
"action": ""
},
"reasons": []
}
```

Comment: Did you figure out what the error is? I'm having the same error and no clue why.

Comment: Any update? i'm having the same problem and nothing is working

Answer (score 26):

I was experiencing this same error and realised the domain wasn't whitelisted in the reCAPTCHA Enterprise console, [which can be accessed here](https://console.cloud.google.com/security/recaptcha).

After adding the domain, the `BROWSER_ERROR` error went away.

Comment: I added 'localhost' and it works now even that i run my website at a port like localhost:4455

Answer (score 4):

The non-beta (`v1`) version of that [page](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.assessments#invalidreason) gives this definition:

> BROWSER_ERROR - A retriable error (such as network failure) occurred on the browser. Could easily be simulated by an attacker.

(I see the `v1beta1` link provided by the OP also contains this definition now, so it may have been updated in the interim.)

Answer (score 0):

I ensured I whitelisted both the backend and the frontend URLs in case they were different; which was my case. You can [whitelist here](https://console.cloud.google.com/security/recaptcha)