# "browser-error" in google reCaptcha V3 (invisible)

Tags: recaptcha-v3, invisible-recaptcha, react-google-recaptcha

I am using google reCaptcha v3 (invisible), but I am getting some response payload with:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "error-codes": [
    "browser-error"
  ]
}
```

I've googled but haven't found any information about "browser-error"

from 7900 reCaptcha v3 requests, 70 are getting the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recaptcha BROWSER\_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67104640/recaptcha-browser-error)

Comment: We are also getting a similar response "Error: browser-error at isRecaptchaInvalid"

Comment: Can you please [edit] to pose a clear, precise question? Maybe your question can be inferred, but this whole site is based on a framework of Q&A, so for the health of the framework, please ask one. You can see [ask] for guidance.

Comment: @Robert that question doesn't have an answer

Comment: @Luis That question has 2 answers. stackoverflow doesn't allow to mark questions without answers as duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that it is related to the Safari browser. Most of this failure comes from users using Safari on iPhones, Ipad, and Macs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please provide mode details whether you managed to resolve the Safari issue.

Comment: I simply check if the request is coming from Safari and let it pass without checking recaptcha.